# Find record name from an hexadecimal record code value using bitwise "and"

Tags: rust

I am writing a function that will retrieve the name of a certain record defined as a `u32`, I wanted to make the function filter the record code first in macro classes and descending to the string value I am looking for.
I wrote the code as below and it works, but I would like to know if there was a more efficient way to implement this.

```rust
pub(crate) const ALLCLSS: u32 = 0x0ffff000;
pub(crate) const SUBCLSS: u32 = 0x0000ffff;

pub(crate) const CLASS_1: u32 = 0x0001f000;
pub(crate) const CLASS_2: u32 = 0x0002f000;
pub(crate) const CLASS_3: u32 = 0x0004f000;
pub(crate) const CLASS_4: u32 = 0x0800f000;

pub(crate) const CLSS1_EVENT_1: u32 = CLASS_1 + 1;
pub(crate) const CLSS1_EVENT_2: u32 = CLASS_1 + 2;
// ...
```

````rust
pub(crate) fn get_record_name_str(record: &Record) -> String {
    let rclass = record.get_code() & ALLCLSS;
    match rclass {
        v if v & CLASS_1 == v => get_class1_name_str(&record),
        v if v & CLASS_2 == v => get_class2_name_str(&record),
        v if v & CLASS_3 == v => get_class3_name_str(&record),
        v if v & CLASS_4 == v => get_class4_name_str(&record),
        _ => format!("UNKNOWN ({:#010X})", rclass),
    }
}

pub(crate) fn get_class1_name_str(record: &Record) -> String {
    let rcode = record.get_code();
    match rcode {
        CLSS1_EVENT_1 => "CLSS1_EVENT_1".to_owned(),
        CLSS1_EVENT_2 => "CLSS1_EVENT_2".to_owned(),
        // ...
    }
}
// ...
```
````

Answer (score 1):

(Not acquainted to Rust.) You have a class range code and an individual event code.

- One could give both a string name, and concatenate them with "_" between.
  This would remove some redundancy. It could be done in the event code "get my class name."
- An other aspect is that the constants are now collected in one source, which forms a version control bottleneck, several peoply adding new constants.
- It would just as well do to have CLASS IDs numbered from 1, and EVENT IDs numbered from 1. The appropriate handling classes could then be (java syntax)

  ```
    class ClsBaseHandler {
        public final int clsId;
        private static final Map<Integer, ClsBaseHandler> handlerMap =
            new HashMap<>();
        protected ClsAbstractHandler(int clsId) {
            this.clsId = clsId;
            ClsBaseHandler old = handlerMap.put(clsId, this);
            assert old == null;
        }
        public String getClassName() {
            return "CLS" + clsId;
        }
    }

    class Cls42Handler extends ClsBaseHandler {
        public Cls42Handler() { super(42); }
    }
  ```

  This is the object oriented way to prevent branched dispatching to `get_class*_name_str`.
- "Class" interferes as a name with the programming lanugae notion `class`. There are some alternatives like "Category".
- Notational: bit masks works with bit OR, probably `|` in Rust. `+` works here, but is slightly misleading.
  The usage of type prefixes or suffixes, here `_str` - if not common in Rust - should not be done. Names tend to lengthen, and the Hungarian notation had its last revival in Microsoft libraries. Better readable.
- `match rclass`: the cases probably could be written shorter. Do not know rust myself.
- The *fail-fast* principle requires not using "UNKNOWN" (but it is nice you at least give the failing ID. Either with `panic!` or an exception `Result<T, E>`.
  In this way errors will not survive long, not being passed on and being hard to retrace.